# SQL - Change NULL value to 0

Tags: sql, null, pivot

I have this pivot table that gives me null value on SUM(contar) and I want to change them to 0

```
SELECT Description AS Categoria,
       [ACS],
       [URO]
FROM
  (SELECT GroupType.Description,
          Speciality.Shortname,
          SUM(1) AS contar
   FROM DoctorEnterpriseDetails
   INNER JOIN Speciality ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Speciality1 = Speciality.SpecialityId
   INNER JOIN GroupType ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId = GroupType.GroupId
   WHERE (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 48)
   GROUP BY GroupType.Description,
            Speciality.Shortname) AS ps PIVOT (SUM(contar)
                                               FOR Shortname IN ([ACS],[URO])) pvt
ORDER BY description
```

I tried make this way but it gives me Null values again

```
SELECT Description AS Categoria,
       [ACS],
       [URO]
FROM
  (SELECT GroupType.Description,
          Speciality.Shortname,
          GroupType.GroupId,
          (CASE WHEN (SUM(1) IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(1) END) AS contar
   FROM DoctorEnterpriseDetails
   INNER JOIN Speciality ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Speciality1 = Speciality.SpecialityId
   INNER JOIN GroupType ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId = GroupType.GroupId
   WHERE (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 48)
   GROUP BY GroupType.Description,
            Speciality.Shortname,
            DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId,
            GroupType.GroupId) AS ps PIVOT (SUM(contar)
                                            FOR Shortname IN ([ACS],[URO])) pvt
ORDER BY GroupId;
```

I don't understand what is wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You define aliases within the CASE, which is not allowed. Additionally you mix numeric and string:

It's either

```
CASE WHEN SUM(1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(1) END AS contador
```

or

```
COALESCE(SUM(1), 0) END AS contador
```

Btw, `SUM(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`